# How can I configure a TF2 server for bots vs. humans?

Tags: team-fortress-2, server-administration

I would like to configure my TF2 server so that whenever a new user joins, they are assigned to a team without bots, only humans. The opposite team should be all bots are on the reverse team.

Is there a way to configure a TF2 server in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the cvar `mp_humans_must_join_team` to either `"red"` or `"blue"` in your server.cfg

The valid values for this cvar are:

- `"any"` (this is the default)
- `"spectator"`
- `"red"`
- `"blue"`

Side note: The cvar is likely ignored for the MvM game mode where players are always put on the RED team.